# How to handle responses from child actors?

Tags: akka

Suppose, we have an actor, which divides tasks into subtasks and delegates them to child actors. This actor does some own work, after it receives responses from all of subactors.

What's the best practice to manage with responses of subactors?

Put their results into, for example, `Map<ActorRef, Object>` and check every time if all replies received?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Composing Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html). It's better to use it in combination with [Routing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html) for children. Something like:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import akka.pattern._
import akka.routing._
import akka.actor._
import akka.util._
import scala.concurrent.duration._


case class Req(i: Int)
case class Response(i: Int)

class Worker extends Actor { def receive = {case Req(i) => sender ! Response(i) }}
class Parent extends Actor {
     import context.dispatcher
     implicit val timeout = Timeout(10, MINUTES) //timeout for response from worker
     val router: ActorRef = 
        context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[Worker]), "router") 
     def processResults(rs: Seq[Response]) = {println(rs); rs}
     def receive = { 
         case t: List[Req] => 
             Future.sequence(t.map(router ? _).map(_.mapTo[Response])).map(processResults) 
     }  
}
```

Results:

```
scala> ActorSystem().actorOf(Props(classOf[Parent])) ! List(Req(1), Req(2), Req(3))

 List(Response(1), Response(2), Response(3))
```

Comment: This pattern is common enough with akka, I wish there was a way that avoids the overhead of ask.

Comment: you mean that ask is creating new actor and promise? don't much big overhead i think. More than that this solution is async, so parent actor do not block. If timeout is a problem - you may just implement it with promise: `class Asker(to: ActorRef, p: Promise) = { ... case resp: Resp => promise.complete(resp); case r: Req => to ! req}`. If you want to avoid actor creation - just move `(to, p)` to internal asker's map and send them with message.

Answer (score 0):

Helo, usually I implement it using List, or if You want Map, of objects type Either: Left and Right (to save information about each actor result - success or fail) and check length of map every time new message from child is received, and when all messages received, send to self message WorkDone or sth with this meaning.

Somewhere in Net I've seen pattern with separate actor created for collecting all messages form childs

superactor:

```
val n = 1000
val collector = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Collector],n)
for( i<-1 to n){
    system.actorOf(Child.props()).!(DoSomeWork)(collector)
}
```

collector

```
class Collector(expectedMsgs: Int) extends Actor {
    var results = someCollection

    def endCollecting() = {
        // You can add here some logic before returning data
        context.parent ! results.toList //or whatever you want
        context.become(afterWork)
    }

    def receive = {
        case r: DataDone =>
            results += Right(r)
            if(results.length>=expectedMsgs){
                endCollecting()
            }
        case r: DataFail =>
            results += Left(r)
            if(results.length>=expectedMsgs){
                endCollecting()
            }
    }

    def afterWork = {
        case _ =>
            // for catch some late or mutiple messages
    }

}
```

Also look at
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/aggregator.html

Comment: What's the point of sending the a `WorkDone` message back to self as opposed to just doing that work inline right there.  Seems like an unnecessary extra hit to the mailbox.  If you were in a `Future` callback there then that might be the right approach, but you're not, so it seems unnecessary.

Comment: In this exact code, Yes, You're right, but this is good place to do some logic after all messages are collected but before returning them, but, maybe better will be impement this using method, I edit this answer